# Método abre todas modais dos elementos do v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in listaProjetosModelos">
     <tr :key="index">
          <td class="text-center">
               {{item.nome_projeto}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
               {{item.departamento}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
               {{item.total_tarefas}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-center text-nowrap">
              <span class="mr-2" @click="show()">Editar</span>
              <span class="mr-2" @click="show()">Excluir</span>
              <span @click="show()">Detalhes</span>

              <!--- MODAL FORM Editar ProjetoModelo -->
              <template>
               <modal name="hello-world">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                           <h2>Editar</h2>
                    </div>
               </modal>
              </template>
           </td>
      </tr>
</template>
```

E o método:

```
 show() {
        this.$modal.show('hello-world', {
            title: 'Editar Projeto Modelo'
        });
    },
```

O que acontece é que se na minha `listaProjetosModelos` tiver 100 itens, e quando eu clicar no `Editar` para editar um item em específico, ele abre todas as 100 modais, ao invés apenas daquele item em específico da minha tabela. 
O que não entendo é porquê isso está acontecendo.
Alguma solução para isto?

Exemplo em execução: https://jsfiddle.net/au12Ley0/

Comment: Cara consegue fazer um exemplo executável pra gente tentar ajudar?

Comment: farei só 1 minut

Comment: Pronto @LeAndrade 
https://jsfiddle.net/au12Ley0/

Comment: Análisando aqui, pude perceber que o que impacta é o modalOpen === true. Isso faz com que abra todas. Mas como fazer apenas uma em específica...

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução é criar um campo dentro do objeto para controlar se o modal está aberto ou não.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    modalOpen: false,
    listaProjetosModelos: [{
        departamento: "Contabilidade",
        nome_projeto: "Nome doido",
        total_tarefas: 0,
        modal: false
      },
      {
        departamento: "Tecnologia",
        nome_projeto: "Tecnologia WOW",
        total_tarefas: 1,
        modal: false
      },
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    abrirModal(index) {
      this.listaProjetosModelos[index].modal = !this.listaProjetosModelos[index].modal
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
#app td{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <template v-for="(item, index) in listaProjetosModelos">
    <tr :key="index">
      <td class="text-center">
        {{item.nome_projeto}}
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        {{item.departamento}}
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        {{item.total_tarefas}}
      </td>
      <td class="text-center text-nowrap">
        <span class="mr-2" @click="abrirModal(index)">Editar</span>
        <span class="mr-2" @click="abrirModal(index)">Excluir</span>
        <span @click="abrirModal(index)">Detalhes</span>
        <!--- MODAL FORM Editar ProjetoModelo -->
        <template v-if="item.modal">
          <modal name="hello-world">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h1>MODAL ABERTA</h1>
            </div>
          </modal>
        </template>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</div>
```

Dessa forma é possível que vários modais sejam abertos ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: é uma opção boa, porém não tenho permissão para implementar o campo na API

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma, pessoal:
Minha modal, antes estava dentro do v-for, então a coloquei fora, e criei um método que recebe o parâmetro do item, que popula as informações dentro desta modal.

https://jsfiddle.net/au12Ley0/15/#

Comment: Desculpa cara, tive que dar um trampo aqui no serviço e não deu para responder. Acho que esta sua solução não é a melhor, pois aí o modal abre fora da tabela. Acredito que a resposta do César lhe atenda de uma maneira melhor, passando um **index** para a função.